# Problemas ao conectar com hive pelo Dbeaver

Tags: jdbc, dbeaver, hive

Estou com um problema ao conectar no hive pelo Dbeaver!

Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://b4fa09-edhhdinsightshadoopgbdev-hdi-dev-gb.azurehdinsight.net:443/finance_hz: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    Connection reset
    Connection reset